# Get most recent groups ordered by users last login date DESC

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

The title makes it sound easy but what I'd like to do is get the last 20 groups from the `groups` table, ordered by their corresponding users last login date. A group can have one or more `users` and ultimately what I want to do is find out which groups have had the least user activity and retrieve the last login date.

Here's the query I came up with -

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.name, user_max.max_login_last_at FROM groups g

LEFT JOIN group_user gu on g.id = gu.group_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(login_last_at) max_login_last_at, u.id
    FROM users u GROUP BY id
) AS user_max ON (user_max.id = gu.user_id)

ORDER BY user_max.max_login_last_at ASC
```

The problem is when I perform the join, it pulls in every `group_user` record and results in duplicates. I feel like there could be an easy solution to this one but I can't seem to figure it out!

**`groups` table**

```
id  name
1   Group 1
2   Group 2
```

**`users` table**

```
id  email   login_last_at
1   user1@example.com   2018-10-17 16:08:47
2   user2@example.com   2018-10-02 15:41:53
3   user3@example.com   NULL
4   user4@example.com   2018-10-08 12:01:48
5   user5@example.com   2018-10-15 9:24:57
6   user6@example.com   2018-10-17 11:10:58
7   user7@example.com   2018-10-17 15:33:03
```

**`group_user` table**

```
id  group_id    user_id
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   1   2
4   1   3
5   1   4
6   2   5
7   1   5
8   2   6
9   1   7
```

Current example result -

```
name    max_login_last_ts
Group 1 2018-10-02 15:41:53
Group 1 2018-10-08 12:01:48
Group 2 2018-10-15 09:24:57
Group 1 2018-10-15 09:24:57
Group 2 2018-10-17 11:10:58
Group 1 2018-10-17 15:33:03
Group 1 2018-10-17 16:08:47
Group 2 2018-10-17 16:08:47
Group 1 2018-10-18 08:55:17
```

The problem is as you can see in the result above is that I'm getting all groups, all I really want is the following -

```
name      max_login_last_ts
Group 2   2018-10-17 16:08:47
Group 1   2018-10-18 08:55:17
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include some sample data, enough to get the point across.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - thanks I'll update with a dataset now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will do what you want. There isn't enough data in your sample to replicate your desired results though.

```
SELECT g.name, MAX(u.login_last_at) AS max_login_last_at
FROM `groups` g
JOIN group_user gu on gu.group_id = g.id
JOIN users u ON u.id = gu.user_id
GROUP BY g.name
ORDER By max_login_last_at DESC
LIMIT 20
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be3224dd1872e943547a6be24886221f)

Comment: You Sir have been incredibly helpful - thank you for this. I've tested against my larger dataset and it does the job perfectly. Appreciate your constructive answer - I knew there was a relatively painless solution out there!